# How to mark the modified fields in a class to be dirty

Tags: java, sql, database, oop, design-patterns

I have a class try to follow the [active record pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern)

```
class MyActiveRecord {
    int id;
    string name;
    int progress;
    ...
}
```

When I try to use this class to update the corresponding row of the SQL Data base, I want to mark the modified field to be "dirty". So, only the modified field, let's say `progress` will update the progress column in the data base.

My question is how to mark the modified field(s) to be dirty?

One way is to create booleans:

```
class MyActiveRecord {
    int id;
    boolean id_dirty;
    string name;
    boolean name_dirty;
    int progress;
    boolean progress_dirty;
    ...
}
```

Another way is to create enums of the fields and having a HashSet to contain the modified field enums.

Which way is better? Or is there another better way to mark the modified field(s) to be dirty?

Comment: This sounds to me like a micro-optimisation.  The usual way is just to mark the whole object as dirty; and if something needs to be updated, just send every field to the database.

Comment: Or to use JPA, which does this for you, instead of hand-writing the logic.

Comment: It's not a micro optimisation if the class(es) have multiple large object fields. Then a lot of network traffic could be saved. However I also agree JPA is still the better option.

Comment: Thanks! But would using JPA be overtreatment?

Answer (score 0):

In my view, there are many pros when you have `HashSet`:

- it will take less space. I mean only dirty fields will be added into `HashSet`
- the overall amount of field will be less. There is no need to add fields like `id_dirty`, `name_dirty;` or `progress_dirty`

So let me show how it would look:

```
public class MyActiveRecord
{
    int _id;
    string _name;
    int _progress;

    HashSet<string> _dirtyFields = new HashSet<string>();

    public void SetId(int id) 
    { 
        _id = id;
        _dirtyFields.Add(nameof(id));
    }
}
```